# Why do I get "The constructor Attribute(String, boolean) is undefined"?

Tags: string, attributes, weka

I'm creating a Instances instance using weka. When I define attributes, I get the following exception: "The constructor Attribute(String, boolean) is undefined". The following is the code I have tried:

```
        ...
        Attribute dtzg = new Attribute("att1Name", 0);
        Attribute pDea = new weka.core.Attribute("att2Name", true);
        ...
```

My pom weka dependency is the following:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
        <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would expect that I would be able to use the constructor "Attribute(java.lang.String attributeName, boolean createStringAttribute)" because it is listed as constructor in the javadoc [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#Attribute-java.lang.String-boolean-)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#Attribute-java.lang.String-boolean-) I was referring to is about the "develop" version of weka, while I imported in my pom the "stable" version of weka. So, if I exchange the dependency above with the following, the compiler does not complain:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
        <artifactId>weka-dev</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I'm curious about the difference between the two versions. I'll ask a question about it, if I'll have time.